# How to start IntelliJ IDEA despite of a plug-in error

Tags: java, plugins, clojure, intellij-idea

I have a problem with my IntelliJ idea 9 IDE. I installed the La Clojure plugin (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4050) and the IDE needed to restart. Now I get the following error on startup and it won't let me continue working:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Source file C:\Users\foo\.IntelliJIdea90\system\plugins\org.intellij.clojure_8192.zip does not exist for action unzip[C:\Users\foo\.IntelliJIdea90\system\plugins\org.intellij.clojure_8192.zip, C:\Users\foo\.IntelliJIdea90\config\plugins]
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.StartupActionScriptManager$UnzipCommand.execute(StartupActionScriptManager.java:189)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.StartupActionScriptManager.executeActionScript(StartupActionScriptManager.java:49)
    at com.intellij.ide.ClassloaderUtil.initClassloader(ClassloaderUtil.java:123)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:35)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

When I couldn't find the zip archive in the specified folder, I manually dropped it in and the IDE correctly extracted it to the config/plugins folder and deleted the zip file from the system/plugins folder. Nevertheless, it didn't solve my problem, the error still exists. Is there a way to start IntelliJ idea disabling the plugin?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Is there a `plugin.xml` config file in your plugins/ directory that specifies which plugins to load at startup? If so, try deleting or commenting out the La Clojure one.

Comment: No there is no plugin.xml config file - but I found another way for solving my problem as explained in my answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-54045) which is already fixed. You can find more details in the issue comments.

Comment: Thank you, though I skimmed the issues briefly I didn't stumple upon this one.

Answer (score 9):

I just had a similar problem, so I thought I'd post the answer:

in your intellij config directory (for intellij 11 & linux this is /home/YOURUSERNAME/.IdeaIC11/config)

there is a txt file called "disabled_plugins.txt"

If there isn't, you can create one.

Just add your plugin to this list and it will not load on startup. (Thus avoiding exceptions and problems with malfunctioning plugins that prevent IDE from starting)

I'm posting this for future reference.

EDIT: Here's my current "disabled_plugins.txt" file for inspiration purposes:

```
ClearcasePlugin
StrutsAssistant
com.intellij.seam.pageflow
com.intellij.velocity
com.intellij.gwt
SourceSafe
Git4Idea
TFS
com.intellij.spring.webflow
CloudBees
com.intellij.spring.roo
com.intellij.spring.integration
com.intellij.spring.batch
com.intellij.spring
org.coffeescript
com.intellij.play
com.intellij.aspectj
GlassFish
com.intellij.appengine
com.intellij.spring.ws
org.intellij.grails
com.intellij.spring.osgi
com.intellij.aop
Weblogic
Resin
com.intellij.seam
com.intellij.tapestry
com.intellij.javaee.view
CloudFoundry
com.intellij.spring.websocket
CVS
com.intellij.dmserver
com.intellij.vaadin
OpenShift
com.intellij.spring.security
CFML Support
JSR45Plugin
PerforceDirectPlugin
com.intellij.struts2
Geronimo
WebSphere
Heroku
com.intellij.seam.pages
com.intellij.freemarker
com.intellij.spring.data
com.intellij.spring.mvc
org.jetbrains.plugins.github
com.intellij.spring.boot
```

Comment: Just a regular text file with each of the plugins you want to disable on a separate line. I'll post my file in my original comment.

Comment: The disabled_plugins.txt file is somehow hard to locate, so finally I search the file through out all files and got it. This method works!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, when installing a bad plugin on my Win10 PC. Idea refused to start and hung on the splash screen.
I solved the problem by

1. Close the hanging instance
2. Go to \AppData\Local\JetBrains<your-idea-version>\plugins and remove latest zip-file containing the plugin
3. Go to \AppData\Roaming\JetBrains<your-idea-version>\plugins and remove latest directory containing the plugin
4. Restart Idea.

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to solve my problem. In the system/plugins folder is a file `action.script`. I savely stored it in another folder and deleted it from the plugins directory. Afterwards idea started without further problems. La clojure runs without problems as well.